# C#, Oracle 9 and entity framework development

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, oracle10g, oracle-xe

I need to develop a local mvc web application for a company. They have an oracle 9 database but they dont want to give access for remote connections. They'll give sample tables and datas but no remote connection allowed so i have to create a development environment. My questions are

1. There is no oracle 9 database download link in oracle web site. Is there any link exists for download database and install on windows 10 (x64) machine for development and testing purposes.
2. Can i use other oracle versions for development like 10g. If sql syntax is same with 9 maybe i can get it work on the site.
3. Is there any chance to use entity framework with oracle 9 database?

Need help from oracle & c# gurus.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not accept such requirements for new developments.

I think Oracle 9i has been deprecated for more than 15 years. Even version 10g has been deprecated many years ago and thus not available anymore.

In general the syntax of Oracle 9i is the same as in current releases, however many function which are nowadays matter of course could be missing in Oracle 9i.

Even if you manage to get a Oracle 9i database it will be hard to connect to such DB with current Oracle client drivers.